# GLEW and glfw compile error: undefined reference to symbol 'XConvertSelection'

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I'm trying to compile this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow* window;

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

int main( void )
{
    // Initialise GLFW
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE,GL_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Playground", NULL, NULL);
    if( window == NULL ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    do{
        // Draw nothing, see you in tutorial 2 !

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
           glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

It's a code from a tutorial I found about OpenGL, I program mostly in Java when it comes to OpenGL, but I wanted to try something new so I went to try in C++.

I'm using QtCreator for this project.
At first I included GLEW and glfw3 libraries:
[image]

And the same for the glfw library file.

And then, when I try compiling the program I get this error:
[image]

In text:

```
$ /home/sapir/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/bin/qmake -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug -o Makefile ../Test/Test.pro
$ g++ -Wl,-rpath,/home/sapir/Qt/5.4/gcc_64 -o Test main.o   -L/home/sapir/Dropbox/Development/Computer/openGLTest/Test/../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lglfw3 -lGLEW -lGLEWmx 
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sapir/Dropbox/Development/Computer/openGLTest/Test/../../../../../../../usr/local/lib//libglfw3.a(glx_context.c.o): undefined reference to symbol 'glXQueryExtension'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Test] Error 1
23:12:13: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Test (kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.0 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
23:12:13: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

I tired searching for an answer in forums and here, but I couldn't find anything that solved this problem.
Anybody got any Ideas?

After adding

```
-lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lGL -lGLU -lXi
```

to the gcc compiler, I get a different error, which contains:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sapir/Dropbox/Development/Computer/openGLTest/Test/../../../../../../../usr/local/lib//libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XConvertSelection'
```

This is my make file: http://pastebin.com/xL5Hpwsf

And this is my .pro file: http://pastebin.com/yhkV7nn7

Comment: The compile errors are virtually unreadable. Please include them as text.

Comment: Open the picture in new tab, you'll be able to see then that way, I'll also include them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, after some research I found that the DSO error which I got means that the order of the includes I've implemented is incorrect and cause the compilation to fail.

So what I did is I used the command:

```
pkg-config --static --libs x11 xrandr xi xxf86vm glew glfw3
```

To get the packages I need for them to run  and in the right order.

Then I compiled the project accordingly.
That's it :)

Comment: You ended hours of frustration

Answer (score 3):

I got same error "undefined reference to symbol 'XConvertSelection'" while compiling example from Irrlicht 3D, solved by adding "-lX11".

Then I got error "undefined reference to symbol 'XF86VidModeGetGamma'", solved by adding "-lXxf86vm"